# Ordering list by date of child page

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

So I have a list that is displaying individual blog pages and they are currently being order by last updated. However I want them ordered by `post.specific.date`. How can I do this? If more code is needed to help please say.

```
{% for post in posts %}

    <div class="...">

        <div class="...">
            {% for item in post.specific.blogpage_images.all|slice:"1" %}
                {% image item.image fill-400x400-c100 %}
                <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="...">
            <h3 class="...">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <h5>{{ post.specific.intro }} <span
                    class="...">{{ post.specific.date }}</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="...">
            {{ post.specific.body|richtext }}

            <div class="...">

                <div class="...">

                    <p>
                        <button class="..."><b><a
                                class="effect-shine"
                                href="{% pageurl post %}">READ
                            MORE »</a></b>
                        </button>

                    </p>

                </div>
                <div class="...">
                    <p>
                        <span class="...">
                            <span class="...">
                                <a href="{% pageurl post %}#disqus_thread"> _
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py code is as follows

```
def home(request):
    posts. Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts,4)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    return render(request, 'base/home.html',{'posts':posts})
```

Models.py is as follows too

```
class BlogIndexPage(Page):

def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        all_posts = BlogPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
       paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 4)
        page = request.GET.get("page")
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context["posts"] = posts
        return context

class BlogPage(Page):
```

Comment: Can you share the code for where you retrieve the posts in your `Page` model?

Comment: The ```view.py``` from where you are passing ```posts``` list is where you can do a sorting on the list as ```post.specific.date``` with list comprehension.And then your html will just work as you intend. Maybe if you could share your code then we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort any `list` with the built-in `sorted` function, and you can specify a correct `key` function for it, to order it however you want:

```
sorted(posts, key=lambda p: p.specific.date)
```

You can use it as part of your loop as well:

```
{% for post in sorted(posts, key=lambda p: p.specific.date) %}
```

Comment: I didn't know that DTL can support sorted() method. Thanks mate for the insight

Comment: I get how this makes sense but I'm getting an error after `sorted` of `%} expected`?

Comment: exact error is `'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for post in sorted(posts, key=lambda p: p.specific.date)`

Comment: @Joelad can you try to define that in your python instead?  Do `date_sorted_posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda p: p.specific.date)` and then `{% for post in date_sorted_posts  %}`

Comment: Thank you! Got that done in models.py!  `date_sorted_posts = sorted(all_posts, key=lambda p: p.specific.date)
        paginator = Paginator(date_sorted_posts, 4)`